# calculating listview & textbox

Tags: c#, listview, textbox

I have been researching for almost two weeks now and found nothing helpful.
I have a listview with a few columns, the last column is a price column, I need to have another column that calculates the price column and a textbox, for each row in the listview. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Sorry, I am new to programming and at the moment I can only sum the column, This is all I got.

```
List<string> last = new List<string>();
last.AddRange(new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" });
int column = 1 ; int.Parse(TextBox1.text)
int row = 0;
foreach (var value in last)
{
    if (!(column >= listView1.Columns.Count))
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
        lvsi.Text = value.ToString();
        listView1.Items[row].SubItems.Insert(column, lvsi);
        row++;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share your code which you have tried and not working ?

Comment: This sounds like a requirement and not a question

Comment: All I am asking is to point me in the right direction

Comment: If you explain what's your purpose of your List<string>, I can understand better what you are tryin to achieve and adapt my code posted to you rrequest.

Comment: This is for a pricelist that is imported from the supplier and this has to be calculated accordingly , convert currency ( Txtbox1 ), add markup ( Txtbox2 ) and add shipping cost ( Txtbox3 ). the checkbox in the listview will allow me to compile a system quote.

Comment: I changed my answer, look af this could solve your question :)

Comment: Highly appreciated Stefano, I'm sure this will help me solve my issue. working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think should be something like this (where n is the number of the column with the price calculated, and i the column with the initial price):

```
int currency = int.Parse(Textbox1.Text);
int markup = int.Parse(Textbox2.Text);
int shippingcost = int.Parse(Textbox3.Text).

foreach(ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
{
  item.SubItems[n].value = ( ((int)item.SubItems[i].value * currency) + markup + shippingcost ).ToString();
}
```

With this, foreach ListViewItem you cast to int the value of the column with the price, calculate the final price with the value of a textbox, and convert it into a string and put the final value the desired column.

Comment: Thanks Stefano, will work on this as I need to have multiple calculations,

Comment: No problem, if you found this useful, sign it as answer ;)